# TypeError .subscribe is not a function

Tags: angular, observable

I'm calling a function in my service from my component. When I try to subscribe to the data being returned I get the following error in my console:

ERROR TypeError: this.entityService.getEntityType(...).subscribe is not a function

It appears that the return in my switch statement is not valid. If I move this function back to my component it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

// component

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

pageConfigs: any;
facility: Facility;
param1: any;
entityConfig: any = {};
snapshot: RouterStateSnapshot;

constructor(
    private modelService: ModelService,
    private entityService: EntityService,
    private pageConfigsService: PageConfigsService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.snapshot = this.router.routerState.snapshot;
    console.log('snapshot', this.snapshot);

    console.log('ngOnInit snapshot url', this.snapshot.url);

    this.entityService.getEntityType(this.snapshot.url)
    .subscribe(
        response => {
            this.param1 = response
            console.log(this.param1);
        }
    );
    console.log('endpoint', this.entityConfig.endpoint);

    this.entityService.getEntities(this.entityConfig.endpoint)
    .subscribe(
        response => {
            this.facility = this.modelService.assignModelFromResponse(this.entityConfig.model, response[0]);
            console.log('facility', this.facility);
        }
    );

    this.pageConfigsService.getPageConfigs('provider_search', 'profile')
    .subscribe(
        response => {
            this.pageConfigs = response;
        }
    );
}
}
```

// service

```
export class EntityService {
entityConfig: any = {};

constructor(
    private firebase: AngularFireDatabase,
    private http: HttpClient
) { }

getEntities(entityType) {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/${entityType}`);
    // return this.firebase.list('providers').valueChanges();
}

getEntityType(model) {
    switch (model) {
        case '/provider-search/profile/1?entity_type=provider':
        this.entityConfig = {
            name: 'providers',
            model: Provider,
            endpoint: 'providers'
        };
        break;
        case '/provider-search/profile/1?entity_type=facility':
        this.entityConfig = {
            name: 'facilities',
            model: Facility,
            endpoint: 'facilities'
        };
        break;
        case '/provider-search/profile/1?entity_type=pharmacy':
        this.entityConfig = {
            name: 'pharmacies',
            model: Pharmacy,
            endpoint: 'pharmacies'
        };
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Not sure how it's compiling for you because break; is unreachable since you have written it after return statement

Comment: Yea, that's an old version of my code. I thought I had to return it because it was in my service. I went ahead an updated it here.

Comment: You can only subscribe to Observables.

Comment: Okay, do you know how to call a synchronous function that lives in my service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getEntityType` implementation is likely incorrect and should be returning a regular dictionary-style object instead of performing an assignment in a `get` method. In order to subscribe to this, you would need to wrap it in an observable of some kind.

Instead of doing that, though, just use it like the synchronous function that it is:

```
getEntityType(...) {
   return { ... }
}

this.entityConfig = this.entityService.getEntityType(this.snapshot.url);
console.log(this.entityConfig);
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I do that it returns undefined. So does the 'this.entityConfig' object.

Comment: `getEntityType` doesn't even return anything, it just sets the instance variable `entityConfig`.

Comment: @London804 What if you write `this.entityService.entityConfig`?